# Count the number of business days between two columns in python (ideally using pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have a df that has two columns with dates in them. I want to find the number of business days between the two columns for each row.

For example, date and date2 are the inputs and bus_days would be the ideal output.

```
Date Date2 Bus_days
3/07 3/13  4
3/08 3/13  3
3/11 3/13  2
3/12 3/13  1
3/13 3/13  0
3/14 3/13  -1
3/15 3/13  -2
```

How do I find the number of business days between date and date2 without looping through the entire df?

I've tried a couple different combinations with no success...

```
df['bus_days'] = (with the following attempts)

[df['date'], df['date2']].asfreq(BDay()).count()
(pd.bdate_range(df['date'], df['date2'])).count()
len(pd.date_range(start=df['date'],end=df['date2'],freq='B'))
((df['date'] - df['date2'])).count()
```

How do I do this?

EDIT:
My dates do have years and are in datetime format.

Comment: Use `np.busday_count`: `df['Bus_days'] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime('2024/'+df['Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d').to_numpy().astype('<M8[D]'), pd.to_datetime('2024/'+df['Date2'], format='%Y/%m/%d').to_numpy().astype('<M8[D]'))`

Comment: Something like this? https://onecompiler.com/python/4276ygban 
I guess logic is there, although you don't have a year so in my example it takes default year 1900.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that my df dates are in datetime format and do have a year on them.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic, you're code worked great. Thank you very much!